# Keras LSTM input from multiple positions over time

Tags: keras, lstm

I'm looking for a way to use Keras LSTM layers to do a classification on time series, each serie is made of 5 [x, y] positions.

my X_datas looks like :

[ [ [xa, ya],[xb, yb],[xc, yc],[xd, yd],[xe, ye] ], 
  [ [][][][][]etc...  ], ... ]

and, as a binary classification, Y_labels is 0 or 1 for each serie.

My problem is, it looks like keras LSTM take a (timestep, dim) input, if I'm right, I have 5 dimentions of 2 dimention each, at each step...

How can I fit my X_datas in my first LSTM layer ?

Thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

Ok I had the vision that, my model does not need to understand my typical data at each step as 5 geographic points of 2 dimensions, it can manage it as a single vector of 10 dimensions...

It compile now, is it a correct assumption ?